# Evaluate a cell once another cell has finished

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-markdown

I use Python Markdown [extension](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/python-markdown/readme.html) so that I can visualize the results nicely (I create an URL from the results). Is there a way to make the cell with the markdown that uses this `{{x}}` notation dependent on a cell where `x` was introduced or changed? Because it's not obvious that user should evaluate a cell with markdown.

better visualization:

```
cell1 (python): 
------------------------------
x=1
url="http://example.com/" + x
------------------------------


cell2 (markdown): 
------------------------------
foo is available on {{url}}
------------------------------
```

And I want the `cell2` to be run when `cell1` is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished by in single cell by using IPython's builtin `Markdown` function to format the output:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown

x=1
url="http://example.com/" + str(x)

Markdown('foo is avalible on '+url)
```